# I'm trying to add breaks after each student name so it writes each name on a different line using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

Here is the javascript code I have done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<body>
<script language = "javascript">
var names = new Array(4);
names[0] = prompt("Enter the students name");
names[1] = prompt("Enter the students name");
names[2] = prompt("Enter the students name");
names[3] = prompt("Enter the students name");
names[4] = prompt("Enter the students name");

document.write("Students name:" + names[0] + "Students name:" + names[1] + "Students 
name:" + names[2]
+ "Students name:" + names[3] + "Students name" + names[4]);

names.sort();

document.write("Students name:" + names[0] + "Students name:" + names[1] + "Students 
name:" + names[2]
+ "Students name:" + names[3] + "Students name" + names[4]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code outputs a response similar to this (array is from user prompt):
Students name:AdamStudents name:brianStudents name:calebStudents name:aaronStudents name:brittStudents name:aaronStudents name:adamStudents name:brianStudents name:brittStudents name:caleb

Im trying to get the code to output like this

Students name:Adam

Students name:brian

Students name:caleb

Students name:britt

Students name:aaron

I tried using \n to do line breaks and 
 to do breaks but adding those made the code fail.

If anyone can share with me how to do the breaks it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [<br>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

```js
document.write("Students name:" + names[0] + "<br>Students name:" + names[1] + "<br>Students 
name:" + names[2]
+ "<br>Students name:" + names[3] + "<br>Students name" + names[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use `<br>` tags like:

```
 document.write("Students name:" + names[0] + "<br> Students name:" + names[1] + "<br> Students 
    name:" + names[2]
    + "<br> Students name:" + names[3] + "<br> Students name" + names[4]);
```

Comment: thansk so much I was not writing it like that